# Where is my CAB file?

Tags: cmd, system, cab

I am making a CAB file from a Directive text file for multiple file compression.  Eveything seems to be working fine; however, I cannot find my newly created CAB file.  This is my first attempt at doing this so I know it has to be something I am doing wrong.  The DDF file I have created seems to be working fine, there is just no file I can find after.  Here is what I am putting in the command:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lazocd>makecab.exe /F C:\Users\lazocd\Desktop\DataLibrary\ss64.ddf /L C
:\Users\lazocd\Desktop
Cabinet Maker - Lossless Data Compression Tool

1,134,955 bytes in 7 files
Total files:              7
Bytes before:     1,134,955
Bytes after:        810,621
After/Before:            71.42% compression
Time:                     0.44 seconds ( 0 hr  0 min  0.44 sec)
Throughput:            2507.59 Kb/second
```

Answer (score 0):

Found It!  It puts it into its own directory by default called disk1.  Just needed to search harder.  Thanks for the views anyways!